# What is the order in which Android looks into the resource files to pick the correct resource when having multiple build-types

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

The project is structured as such:

Inside the :app module:
src/
├ debug/res/mipmap...
├ main/res/mipmap...
├ release/res/mipmap...

And I had ic_launcher.png defined in all of these places, inside the res of /release, of /main and of /debug

For the release build it was picking up the icon from /main, ignoring what was inside /release. So I am trying to understand, how does this decision making work exactly? Where can I find some material to read up on to properly understand this, since I can't find the relevant information in the docs.

This all came to my mind as we've had the wrong launcher icons inside /release/res/mipmap... and it luckily didn't show in the actual release version, but I do not understand how this is possible.

When I do the same with string resources, having some string defined in all of these sources, the strings from inside /release/res/values takes precedence over the ones in /main/res/values.

Comment: It looks like `main/res` acts like a `default` or `release` folder, would it be possible to you to use that instead? Not sure about the case with string thought. Also you can introduce some additional level of resources separation using flavors https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants